# MVC Areas - Controller does not return view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have some problems using Areas in my MVC project. I'm able to access my controller, which is located under the area, but when it returns to view (with model), I get an error:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations.The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/MyController/Index.aspx ~/Views/MyController/Index.ascx etc.

Here is the MyAreaAreaRegistration:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
     context.MapRoute(
        "MyArea_default",
        "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

Routeconfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default", // Route name
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "MyApp.Controllers" }
            );
```

Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
     ...
     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

And controller:

```
return View(myViewModel);
```

I'm totally stuck with this one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please change your route config code .

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default", // Route name
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ).DataTokens.Add("area", "MyArea"); ;
```

It will be work for you .

Thanks .

Comment: Hi, thx this indeed works for this view in this area, but I have also views and controllers outside the Areas (the "main application"), and these stopped working. If I change to DataTokens.Add("area", ""), then others work, but area doesn't.